# bash script: how to insert text between two specific characters

Tags: bash, awk, sed

For example, I have a file containing a line as below:

```
"abc":"def"
```

I need to insert `123` between `"abc":"` and `def"` so that the line will become: `"abc":"123def"`.

As `"abc"` appears only once so I think I can just search it and do the insertion.

How to do this with bash script such as `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: you should know by now that you need to show your own effort while asking a question..

Comment: @Sundeep well, I know how to use `sed` to replace something... And I try to google but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: that is no excuse... the question still feels like give me code for free... a simple search and replace would be `sed 's/"abc":"def"/"abc":"123def"/'` if you didn't know about capture groups and back-references... there are plenty of resources https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info and SO doc itself has info: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/topics .. you have to put effort to learn

Comment: @Sundeep  I told you: i've known how to use sed to do search and replace. Now I don't want to replace because the line is very long, I need to insert something.

Comment: if `sed 's/"abc":"def"/"abc":"123def"/'` doesn't solve your problem, you need to update the question with a case where this solution fails

Comment: @Sundeep  it doesn't fail. I just don't want to use it. Because in my real case, `def` is very long. So I need the insertion. You can also try to google things like `sed insert string` and to see the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AMD$ sed 's/"abc":"/&123/' File
"abc":"123def"
```

Match `"abc":"`, then append this match with `123` (`&` will contain the matched string `"abc":"`)

If you want to take care of space before and after `:`, you can use:

```
sed 's/"abc" *: *"/&123/'
```

For replacing all such patterns, use `g` with `sed`.

```
sed 's/"abc" *: *"/&123/g' File
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(:")(.*)/\1123\2/' <<<'"abc":"def"'
"abc":"123def"
```

- `(:")` gets `:"` and put in captured group 1
- `(.*)` gets the remaining portion and put in captured group 2
- in the replacement, `\1123\2` puts `123` between the groups

---

`awk`:

```
$ awk -F: 'sub(".", "&123", $2)' <<<'"abc":"def"'
"abc" "123def"
```

In the `sub()` function, the second (`$2`) field is being operated on, pattern is used as `.` (which would match `"`), and in the replacement the matched portion (`&`) is followed by `123`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '"abc":"def"'| awk '{sub(/def/,"123def")}1'

"abc":"123def"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.